# Are there any good white and/or blue token generators?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I’m looking for something that’ll summon 1 or more tokens per turn so I can use [Soul Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%20Warden%5d) and [Ajani's Pridemate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%27s%5d%2b%5bPridemate%5d) at full power. Can be in modern, legacy, or standard but I prefer modern. Thank you :)

Comment: Standard? Modern? Legacy? Vintage? Commander? Something else?

Comment: Modern, legacy, and/or standard, but I prefer modern

Answer (score 4):

If you accept planeswalkers as your tool to generate tokens multiple turns you may use one of these:

- [Dovin, Grand Arbiter](https://scryfall.com/card/rna/167/dovin-grand-arbiter) as a Blue and White option
- [Karn, Scion of Urza](https://scryfall.com/card/dom/1/karn-scion-of-urza) as a Colorless option
- [Nahiri, the Lithomancer](https://scryfall.com/card/c14/10/nahiri-the-lithomancer) as a Mono White option
- [Ugin, the Ineffable](https://scryfall.com/card/war/2/ugin-the-ineffable) as a Colorless option
- [Tezzeret, Artifice Master](https://scryfall.com/card/m19/79/tezzeret-artifice-master) as a Mono Blue option

Now if you want creatures, these are the two best options I've got:

- [Mycologist](https://scryfall.com/card/plc/27/mycologist) as a Mono white option
- [Pallid Mycoderm](https://scryfall.com/card/mma/24/pallid-mycoderm) also as a Mono White option